Trying to prove monotone-sequences property ⇒ Archimedean property

Monotone-sequences property ⇒ Archimedean property

Today I just started learning this and having trouble understanding parts of the proof. Sorry if these are easy to some, I just couldn't find this answered online.
I am using here Archimedean property $\frac{1}{n}→0$. I also have to use this lemma:
Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence and suppose that $a_n \to a$. If $(\forall n)\, a_n \leq x$, then $a\leq x.$
My proof:
We observe that $\frac{1}{n}$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$. Then by the Monotone Sequences Property, it converges to some limit $\delta$. Noticing $\frac{1}{n} > 0$ for all $n$, applying the lemma, we get $\delta \geq 0$.
Assume for contradiction that $\delta > 0$.
Let's set $\epsilon = \delta$. Since $\frac{1}{n} \to \delta$, by the definition of convergence, there exists $N$ such that for all $n \geq N$, we have: $\left|\frac{1}{n} - \delta\right| < \delta$.
This simplifies to: $0 < \frac{1}{n} < 2\delta$ for all $n \geq N$.
Now, since this holds for all $n \geq N$, consider specifically $n \geq 4N$. For such $n$, we have: $\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{4N}$.
Since $\frac{1}{N} < 2\delta$, multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{4}$ gives: $\frac{1}{4N} < \frac{\delta}{2}$.
Combining these results, for $n \geq 4N$, we get: $\frac{1}{n} \leq \frac{1}{4N} < \frac{\delta}{2}$.
This contradicts our earlier conclusion that $0 < \frac{1}{n} < 2\delta$ for all $n \geq N$, because $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{\delta}{2}$ implies that $\delta$ is not the smallest bound. Thus, the assumption $\delta > 0$ must be false.
Therefore, $\delta = 0$.
My question:
How exactly are we getting the contradiction here from $\frac{1}{n} < 2\delta$ and $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{\delta}{2}$? Clearly $\frac{\delta}{2}$ fits into the interval $0 < \dots < 2\delta$, so they both can be true. So where are we getting at?

Be careful that the property you mention has both $\le$ inequalities in it, i.e., $a_n \le x$ implies $a \le x$. However, you try to use it by replacing both by $>$, i.e., $a_n > x$ implies $a > x$. That is not true. What is actually true in the case of having $>$ is the following. $a_n > x$ implies $a \ge x$ (the analogue for reverse directions also holds).

Thanks a lot, for some reason I didn't know that. Guess that answers my first question!

For $(1)$: This is not from the lemma. If a sequence $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is non-negative and decreasing, then the limit of the sequence has to be greater or equal to $0$. Formal proof:
Suppose that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}a_n=l$ and $l<0$, then by definition, $$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in \mathbb{N}, s.t. \ for \ all \ n>N(n\in \mathbb{N}), we\ have  \ |a_n-l|<\epsilon $$
By choosing $\epsilon=-\frac{l}{2}$, we have $\frac{3l}{2}<a_n<\frac{l}{2}$, contradiction.
For $(2)$: Not necessarily to choose $n>4N$. Actually, we want to get a converse result of $\delta \leq\frac{1}{n},\forall n\in \mathbb{N}.$
We have already $\frac{1}{N}<2\delta,$ then multiply $\frac{1}{4}$ on both sides to get $\frac{1}{4N}<\frac{\delta}{2}$, thus there exsits $n\in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\frac{1}{n}<\frac{\delta}{2}<\delta$.
For instance, you can also multiply $\frac{1}{3}$ on both side, then choose $n>3N$, there are many choices.

Thanks, though I am still somewhat confused how do we go from $\frac{1}{n}<2 \delta (\forall n \geq N)$ to $\frac{1}{N}<2\delta$. Is it the same $N$ as in $\forall n \geq N$? And why can we change $n$ to $N$ here given that we have $\forall n \geq N$?

@Tomas We first choose $N$(such $N$ always exists) and fix it, then choose some $n$ with the condition $n>4N.$

@Tomas Your statement is not true and it's not used in the proof。

So am I correct in interpreting that from condition $\forall n \geq N$ we can guarantee that $\exists n=2N$, and from this we get $\frac{1}{2N}<2 \delta$, which contradicts our previous $\frac{1}{n}<2 \delta$, or am I misunderstanding something?

@Tomas For all $n>2N$, we have $\frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{2N}<2\delta$, contradicts to $\delta \leq \frac{1}{n}$ ($\delta$ is the limit of the sequence and this sequence is decreasing, thus NOT $\frac{1}{n}\leq 2\delta)$

I updated my proof, can you check if I understand it correctly now?

@Tomas It's ok now, but for $\delta \geq 0$, it's both from the lemma and my answer $(1)$.

@BoweiTang your comment that "we first choose $N$ (such $N$ always exists)" might be misleading: knowing $\frac{1}{n}<2\delta$ for all $n \geq N$ certainly implies the assertion for $n=N$, i.e. $\frac{1}{N}<2\delta$. That is why you can choose such an $N$. Once you have it though, it is immediate that $\frac{1}{4N}<\delta/2$ which contradicts $\frac{1}{n}\geq \delta$ for all $n\geq 1$.

This might help clarify where the contradiction comes from:
The sequence $(\frac{1}{n})_{n \geq 1}$ is decreasing and bounded below by $0$, thus the monotone sequence property ensures that it converges, and we may set $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = \delta$.
Claim: $\delta$ is the greatest lower bound for the set $\{\frac{1}{n}: n \geq 1\}$
Proof: We first show that $\delta \geq \ell$ for any lower bound for the set $\{\frac{1}{n}: n \geq 1\}$: If $g\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$ and $\delta<g$, then for all $n\geq 1$ we have $|\frac{1}{n}-\delta|=\frac{1}{n}-\delta>g-\delta>0$, contradicting the assumption that $\frac{1}{n}\to \delta$.
On the other hand, we claim that $\delta\leq 1/n$ for all $n\geq 1$. Indeed if this is not the case, then there exists an $N>0$ with $\delta> \frac{1}{N}$ then for all $n \geq N+1$ we have $\delta-\frac{1}{n}>\frac{1}{N}-\frac{1}{N+1} = \frac{1}{N(N+1)}>0$. Since the sequence is decreasing and $\frac{1}{n}\geq 0$ for all $n$, we have $0\leq \delta \leq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \geq 1$.
[The same proof shows that if $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is any decreasing sequence then its limit (if it exists) is the greatest lower bound of the set of its values.]
Claim: $\delta=0$.
Proof: Informally speaking, if $\delta>0$ we get a contradiction because we have to have $\frac{1}{n}\geq \delta$ for all $n$, but for very large $n$ we should have $\frac{1}{n}$ very close to $\delta$ so that $\frac{1}{2n}$ is very close to $\delta/2$, and $\delta/2 <\delta$ so that this will mean $\frac{1}{2n}<\delta$, contradicting the fact that $\delta\leq \frac{1}{2n}$. Once you see this, it is not hard to make it rigorous: If $\delta>0$ then there is a $N>0$ such that $0\leq \frac{1}{n}-\delta<\delta$ and hence $\delta\leq \frac{1}{n}<\delta$ for all $n \geq N$. But then for all $n \geq N$ we have $\frac{1}{2n}<\delta/2<\delta$
Alternative proof:
Another way to organize this argument is to use the fact that if a sequence $(a_n)_{n \geq 1}$ converges to a limit $\ell$ then any subsequence $(a_{n_k})_{k \geq 1}$ also converges to $\ell$. It follows that if $(\frac{1}{n})_{n \geq 1}$ converges to $\delta$, then setting $n_k= 2k$ we see that $(\frac{1}{2k})_{k \geq 1}$ must converge to $\delta$. But $\frac{1}{2k} = \frac{1}{2}.\frac{1}{k} \to \frac{1}{2}\delta$, hence we must have $\delta = \frac{1}{2}\delta$ so that $\frac{1}{2}\delta =0$ and hence $\delta =0$.

Thanks, I have few questions though for first proof. 1) why are we assuming (how do we know) $\delta$ is a lower bound beforehand 2) from line $\delta-{\frac{1}{n}}>{\frac{1}{N}}-{\frac{1}{N+1}}={\frac{1}{N(N+1)}}>0$ don't we get $\delta>{\frac{1}{n}}$ instead of $\delta\leq1/n$?

I've tried to give provide more details in the first proof, but the goal is to show two things: first that $\delta$ has to be at least as big as any lower bound, and then that it is, itself, a lower bound. For the latter point, if it is not a lower bound, then there is an $N$ with $\delta>1/N$ and hence for all $n>N$, $\delta>1/N>1/n$ and $|\delta-1/n|>|\delta-1/N|>0$, giving a contradiction.
